# How can I color a Curve by the value of a kdim with Holoviews?

Tags: python, holoviews

I would like to `.overlay` on key dimension, but also use a gradient palette to color the Curve by the value of the key dimension.

So a simple overlay would be

```
%%opts Curve [show_legend=False]
hv.HoloMap({i:hv.Curve([i]*100) for i in range(10)}, ["i"]).overlay("i")
```

with horizontal lines.

How can I use `matplotlib.cm.viridis` colors with a gradient from `i=0` blue to `i=9` yellow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw multiple paths it is usually best to use the Path and Contours element. More specifically, if each curve you want to draw has a single value associated with it the Contours element is most appropriate. To do what you want you create a list of curves with x and y values along with the appropriate value of 'i' as dictionaries, which you can then pass to the Contours constructor. The final step is to declare 'i' as a value dimension (vdim) of the Contours and set `color_index='i'` and `cmap`:

```
curves = [{'x': np.arange(100), 'y': [i]*100, 'i': i} for i in range(10)]
hv.Contours(curves, vdims=['i']).options(color_index='i', cmap='viridis')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Where could I find the documentation for `color_index`? Is there an easy way to convert between my HoloMap and the Contours version? I usually start with a HoloMap.

Comment: There is a section on the color_index here:

http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Styling_Plots.html

Comment: I'll have a look! I was having trouble finding it in the official API, where I would usually expect to find everything. Is there a convenient way to get from HoloMap to this form? I assumed Holoviews suggests HoloMap as the starting point for everything - which also makes sense to me. Often I need individual curves, but sometimes I want to combine them, but label by continuous color.